# Bootstrap-related issue

Tags: statistics

Say I re-sample $N$ items with replacement from a numbered item sample of size $N$. What is the average number of data items that are not selected in each such sampling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  what is the probability that a specific item is not sampled in $1$ draw?  what is the probability that it is not sampled in $N$ draws?  Now use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: If you could elaborate... the probability that a specific item is not sampled in $N$ draws is $[(N-1)/N]^N$.

Comment: @Omri:  so the average number you would expect not to be sampled at all is $N\left( \frac {N-1}N \right)^N$.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, the average portion of $N$ that is not sampled approaches $1/e$  as $N$ goes to infinity...